# dplyr mutate calling a function with incorrect results

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 460K observations loaded into a data frame named `data`. One of the variables is defined as follows:

```
$ exeroft1  <int> NA, 105, NA, 205, NA, 102, 220, 102, 102, 220, 230, NA, NA, 105, 102, 210, 203, NA, NA, 107, 103, NA, 203, NA, NA, 105, 107, NA, 102, NA, 107, NA, 107, 103, ...
```

I need to pass each value of `exeroft1` to the following function, which converts the value into another value:

```
calculateWeeklyExercise <- function(value) {
    if (value > 200) {
        timesWeekly = (value - 200) / 4
    } else {
        timesWeekly = (value - 100)
    }

    timesWeekly
}
```

Here is some R code that does all the processing:

```
data %>%
    # Filter missing values
    filter(!is.na(exeroft1)) %>% 

    # Add a column to the data frame which represents exercise rate
    mutate(weeklyExercise = calculateWeeklyExercise(exeroft1)) %>%

    # Select some values
    select(educa, sex, exeroft1, weeklyExercise)
```

When I execute this code, I get the following warning, which I do not understand:

```
Warning message:
In if (value > 200) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I'm not very experienced with R. It seems that the value I'm passing to the function is not being treated as a integer, even though it is. For any value < 200, the correct value is calculated. For any value > 200, it's not. So, essentially, in the function, only the else clause seems to ever get executed.

Comment: It is related to the `if/else` problem when you have length > 1.  Use `ifelse`  Or if we are applying for each row, then `data %>%
    # Filter missing values
    filter(!is.na(exeroft1)) %>% rowwise() %>%>` and do it.

Comment: @akrun - I don't understand though. Why is 'value' being treated as having a length > 1 when it's an integer?

Comment: if I understand (without a reproducible example), the value is taking a column as input and the column have length > 1.  i.e. `if(1:3 >2) 1` get the same warning

Comment: or `calculateWeeklyExercise <- Vectorize(calculateWeeklyExercise)` and run again. but you need a condition to handle NA in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we modify the function to use `ifelse` ie. the vectorized form of `if/else` which can take multiple values, then it should work

```
calculateWeeklyExerciseNew <- function(value) {
  ifelse(value > 200, 
           (value - 200) / 4,
              value - 100)

 }
```

---

The warning message is obvious as the OP's function is applied to a column of dataset where the number of elements are greater than 1.  As `if/else` takes only a single observation, it throws the warning. i.e.

```
if(1:3 >2) 1
```

> Warning message: In if (1:3 > 2) 1 :   the condition has length > 1
>   and only the first element will be used

In the above example, we have a vector of length 3 (`1:3`), and it gives the warning, suppose if we do with `ifelse`

```
ifelse(1:3 >2, 1, 0)
#[1] 0 0 1
```

However, we can still use the OP's function to take only a single observation by doing the `rowwise` i.e.

```
data %>%
    filter(!is.na(exeroft1)) %>% 
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(weeklyExercise = calculateWeeklyExercise(exeroft1)) %>%
    select(educa, sex, exeroft1, weeklyExercise)
```

but, it would be slower.

Comment: Thank you. Great explanation.

Comment: Just an FYI, I tried the ifelse and I'm still getting the warning, and incorrect results.

Comment: @RandyMinder You haven't provided a reproducible example for me to test it.  My suggestion was based on the warning you showed.

Comment: Your answer is still useful and the rowwise suggestion works perfectly.

Comment: @RandyMinder  Can you change the `ifelse` to `if_else` (dplyr specific)

Comment: Generates the same warning

Comment: @RandyMinder That's interesting.  It should have worked though.  Can you update your post with a small reproducieble example using `dput` i.e. `dput(droplevels(head(data, 20)))`